# Sort Sql Result By Two Order

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a movie database and I want to get result first according year desc then movie_name desc.

here is an example.

```
 year       movie_name
_____________________
 2011       dil toh
 2011       no one killed
 2010       Tees maar khan
 2010       ishqiya
```

Now I want the out put as

```
dil toh
no one killed
ishqiya
Tees maar khan
```

So what will be the sql query ? please help me.

Every ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get result first according year desc then movie_name desc.

Try this:

```
SELECT movie_name
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY year DESC, movie_name DESC
```

But in your example the movie_names are in *ascending* order not descending order. To specify ascending order instead of `DESC` you can write `ASC`. Note that `ASC` is optional. Ascending order is the default so this will also work:

```
SELECT movie_name
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY year DESC, movie_name
```

Comment: @Suman: Despite being asked, you have still failed to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is

```
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `movie_name` ASC
```